# Display get dynamic data in Chart.js with PHP and JS

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, charts

I want to dynamically display statistics with Chart.js on my page from different users.

I can already display data with a clear data query from one user, but several identical bootstrap cards with different data should be displayed. How can I pass the user variables dynamicly to the mysqli_query in **playerOne.php**?

**playerOne.php**

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');

include "../../../includes/db.php";

$query = "SELECT SUM(game_stats.match_stats_kills) AS Kills, SUM(game_stats.match_stats_deaths) AS Deaths FROM game_stats WHERE game_stats.user_id = 1";
$select_kd = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

$data = array();
foreach($select_kd as $row) {
    $data[] = $row;
}

mysqli_close($connection);

echo json_encode($data);
```

**stats.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    showData();
});

function showData() {
{
    ($.post("includes/stats/playerOne.php",
    function(data) {

        var kills = [];
        var deaths = [];

        for(var i in data) {
            kills.push(data[i].Kills)
            deaths.push(data[i].Deaths);
        }

        var pieChartData = {
            labels: [
                'Kills', 'Deaths'
            ],
            datasets: [
                {
                    backgroundColor: ['#f56954', '#00c0ef'],
                    data: [kills, deaths]
                }
            ]
        };

        var pieChartTarget = $('#playerKD').get(0).getContext('2d');

        var pieChart = new Chart(pieChartTarget, {
            type: 'pie',
            data: pieChartData
        });
    }));
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can send the variable on the url, here...

```
($.post("includes/stats/playerOne.php?user=1",  // <-- add variable here -- ?user=1
```

then in your php, access the value of the variable using...

```
$_GET['user']
```

e.g.

```
$query = "SELECT SUM(game_stats.match_stats_kills) AS Kills, SUM(game_stats.match_stats_deaths) AS Deaths FROM game_stats WHERE game_stats.user_id = " + $_GET['user'];
```